# Implicit loop for filling a dimension variable

Tags: loops, fortran, dimension

I need help to understand why I cannot compile this code

```
program test
 integer,dimension(1:10) :: isquares
 isquares(:) = (j**2,j=1,10)
 print*,isquares
end
```

However, this version is ok:

```
program test
 print*,(j**2,j=1,10)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(j**2,j=1,10)` is a implicit loop. For an assignment, you need to convert this into an array first:

```
isquares(:) = [(j**2,j=1,10)]
```

Comment: Right, but this feature are only available in Fortran 2003 version.  jsquares(:) = [(j**2,j=1,10)]                                                                                                                                  
               1                                                                                                                                                
Error: Fortran 2003: [...] style array constructors at (1)

Comment: Then use `(/ (j**2,j=1,10) /)`